# Setting up notifications for physical key press combinations

Tags: bash, input, notifications, keyboard, debian

I've got a Royal Kludge RK61 60% keyboard that has different modes depending on a few different combinations of FN + <ENTER, CTRL, WINKEY>. Unfortunately, there is no actual indication as to which mode the keyboard has selected in any way. I'm looking to change that with my extremely limited bash knowledge by implementing a notification upon key press.

I've done a bit of searching over the past couple days trying to find out the input data for the keys so that it can be incorporated into code.

I found some code that seems to do what I want it, but I think my incorporation of the data needed is flawed, or even wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
read $key input
if [ "$input" = "keysym 0x1008ff2b" + "keysym 0xff0d" ]; then
    notify-send -u normal -i $HOME/Downloads/keyboard_icon.jpeg "Keyboard is now in Function mode:" " Arrow Keys on"
fi
done
```

Is this correct? How do I ensure that it would be executed without needing the console open?

Comment: Is this shortcut even sent to the PC? Maybe the keyboard catches it on its internal controller and hides it from the PC. Please check this using `xev` (in case you have X-based GUI running). Anyways, https://unix.stackexchange.com might be a better fit for this type of question. A script like this won't work. You have to dive deeper into the system. Therefore the question is more about Linux and less about programming.

Comment: `xev` doesn't recognize the input from the RK61, but does recognize it from my laptop's keyboard which I thought was interesting.

I'll definitely check out over there! Thank you.